# Get all records from Table When no records in Mapping Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables in join. Here i have to get mapped records when the Second table has set of records. But when the Second table has no record i need all records from first table.

```
Create Table #temp1
(Id1 int)
Create Table #temp2
(Id2 int)

Insert into #temp1 Values(1),(2),(3),(4)
Insert into #temp2 Values(1),(2)

Select * from #temp1 A
Inner Join #temp2 B On A.Id1=B.Id2
```

**It gives correct output when i have records in second table.**

[image]

**But when i have no records in second table i need to get all records from first table.**

```
Delete #temp2

Select * from #temp1 A
Inner Join #temp2 B On A.Id1=B.Id2
```

this query return no records i tried with Left Outer Join it give all records but i am not getting records like first scenario.

```
Drop Table #temp1
Drop Table #temp2
```

**I need output like this.**

[image]

Thanks in Advance.
if question is not clear ,please ask me.

Comment: Just change your INNER join to a LEFT join. You should probably take a look at this link to understand joins better. http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/?_sm_au_=iHVPPtrT7MR74flH

Comment: _"tried with Left Outer Join i give all records but i am not getting first scenario."_ Show that approach and tell us what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want columns from the first table:

```
select a.*
from #temp1 a
where exists (select 1 from #temp2 b where b.id2 = a.id1) or
      not exists (select 1 from #temp2 b);
```

If you wanted the extra columns from the second table, you could use `union all`:

```
Select a.*, b.*
from #temp1 a Inner Join
     #temp2 b
     On a.Id1 = b.Id2
union all
select a.*, b.*
from #temp1 a left join
     #temp2 b
     on a.id1 = b.id2
where not exists (select 1 from #temp2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you *can* use an `OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT Id1 FROM  #temp1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN  #temp2 t2
    ON t1.Id1 = t2.Id2
```

Answer (score 0):

`Left join` seems to work fine:

```
Select a.id1
from #temp1 A
left Join #temp2 B On A.Id1=B.Id2
```

[**Demo here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/4689/0)